# Click event listener not working withouth any error in console

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a sample menu that I took from CodePen, which can be found in the following link and actually works as intended in the CodePen site: https://codepen.io/syrizaldev/pen/QWmdGwe

However, after I am using that exact code in my website, when I click the burger menu in order to pop the mobile version, it just wont show and wont show any errors in console either.

This is the JavaScript code (not full, but the one that might be messing up somewhere):

```
const navbarMenu = document.getElementById("menu");
const burgerMenu = document.getElementById("burger");
const headerMenu = document.getElementById("header");

// Open Close Navbar Menu on Click Burger
if (burgerMenu && navbarMenu) {
   burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
      burgerMenu.classList.toggle("is-active");
      navbarMenu.classList.toggle("is-active");
   });
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Header Section -->
<header class="header" id="header">
   <nav class="navbar container">
      <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="#"></a>
      <div class="burger" id="burger">
         <span class="burger-line"></span>
         <span class="burger-line"></span>
         <span class="burger-line"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu" id="menu">
         <ul class="menu-inner">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">MENU ITEM</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="menu-block">MENU ITEM</a>
   </nav>
</header>
```

If I try to input bot of these in the Chrome console, both of them return the HTML correct div, so its not that the elements cannot be found

```
document.getElementById("burger");
document.getElementById("menu");
```

As a hint, the menu is designed to add and remove classes on scroll with the following code:

```
// Change Header Background on Scrolling
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
   if (this.scrollY >= 85) {
      headerMenu.classList.add("on-scroll");
   } else {
      headerMenu.classList.remove("on-scroll");
   }
});
```

But that is throwing an error in the Chrome console whenever I scroll

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

**EDIT: Defering the embedded script as @Quentin and @Erhan Çapar stated solved the problem.**

```
<script src="js/header.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you just forgot the `<script>` element.

Comment: Re edit. Oh. You didn't forget it. You put it in the `<head>` and didn't `defer` it.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine, so there is something else going on. You should add an `else` block and throw an error. `if (burgerMenu && navbarMenu) { ... } else { throw new Error('Could not find burger or nav menus'); }`... and troubleshoot from there. Are you waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` before running any JS code? Are you using react or some other framework?

Comment: You forgot to defer your script so when the javascript loads, the html is not yet loaded, causing your script to not find the elements you are referring to. You can either put the <script> tag to the end of your file or just add the defer property like <script  src="..." defer>

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping. Defering the script solved it.